# How do I bake these materials without getting the "circular dependency" or No active Image" errors?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have imported a small 3d building model from a practice photogrammetry drone mission. I'm not familiar with the blender baking process, and I have been struggling to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7bjdWu9OGs&t=0s&ab_channel=WillW) on how to bake the materials without getting errors. I keep getting a "circular dependency for image" error, or if not then I get "no active image found in material" error.

The process I've tried to follow is

- Create & assign a new UV map
- Create and assign a new image texture
- smart Unwrap the UV onto the texture image
- Create & assign a new material
- Create an image texture node on the material, set to the new texture
- Press bake, get errors
- Proceed to redo process in slightly different ways numerous times and continually fail

I get the circular dependency error from this. I've tried numerous other adjustments to this process, including flipping normals (read somewhere that may help??), occasionally I've had the "no active image found" but I can't seem to get the process right.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

[Link to the folder with the blender files and drone imagery](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tp2raQ_TXCZeMF_HJhe3ofl2iRFCn7as?usp=sharing) (the OBJ file is in the textures folder)

Screenshot 1: Node setup prior to bake
[image]

Screenshot 2: Material set up prior to bake
[image]

Screenshot 3: Circular Dependency Error message during bake
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set up this way?

[image]

The image should be selected, but it doesn't mean that it should be connected in some way.

Comment: I'm sure I have, but tried again just now to be certain. Got the same circular dependency error. Always from object "odm_textured_model_geo" but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Are you sure that all materials have active image disconnected from the main tree? Since you have a lot of materials, every one of them can cause this error.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I must have completely removed all the nodes at least once before, because after you suggested it I just deleted all the nodes for those materials and got the "No image in matieral" error. When I tried again but just disconnected them, it worked.

Thanks again!!